# Parsing a text file, to be HTML compatible?

Tags: javascript, java, html, json, parsing

I have a number of text files in the format:

(400,  530); 6.9; 5.7; 5.0;------> continues for 100 values.

(500,  530); 7.9; 5.1; 5.0;

(600,  530); 6.7; 6.7; 7.2;

where the coordinates are in the brackets, followed by 100 values.
I don't know if "parse" is the correct word, (I'm a newbie), but I want to attack this text file so that a webpage can process a pair of inputted coordinates, and get one of the 100 values and output it out.

I'm completely at a loss with how to do this, what language would be suitable? (One that I'd be able to output the results from to HTML)

And if someone were to provide an example I'd be very grateful.
Thanks

Comment: Every programming language is capable of doing this task. Pick the one you prefer and it will be fine.

Comment: If you want an Output in a HTML, the where the data file would be located, on the client or on a distant server. If the last, you will need to communicate with a server, send a HTTP request to get the result. If everything is local, you could check with Javascript to stay simple. But as said, this could be done in thousand solution

Comment: What is the extent of the problem? Do you need to automate conversion of files that are coming from somewhere (from where and how can they be accessed) or are there just a few existing files that need to do be converted (how many)?

Comment: @Traktor53 There are 9,000 lines in the file, each with 100 values=900,000 values per file (and i have 6 text files that the HTML page might have to reference). User inputs coordinates and the program gets the relevant value from the file (will always be in format "1.0" (one decimal place). They don't neccessarily need to be converted, just need my code to find the relevant value and output it. Preferable server side so would php be suitable?

Comment: So if each value is 6 bytes of text after JSON formatting (quotes and a separator), that's getting up to 36 MB of text data. Assuming you don't send that all to the browser, what server and possibly database technology are you planning to use?

Comment: I assume it would be a bad idea to have the files client-side? I have server space on godaddy.com, where the website will be hosted. I wasn't planning to use database technology, I assumed it would be sufficient to just get the value from the file once the user specified coordinates. Should I be using a database?

Comment: Here's a plan. Convert the 6 file into lots of smaller files, each formatted using JSON,  and when the user enters co-ordinates, do an AJAX call to retrieve the file, converted from JSON back into an object, and look the coordinates up in client side javascript. You could write a node.js program do do the iniitial conversion on your PC, or use any language you like. It's all yours :D

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend you to store the source data into an easily accessible variables. Selecting the type of variable depends on how you want to access the data. Therefore, just an example in PHP:

```
$source = "(400, 530); 6.9; 5.7; 5.0;";
$pieces = explode(";", $source);
echo '<p>'.$pieces[0].'</p>'; // (400, 530)
echo '<p>'.$pieces[1].'</p>'; // 6.9
```

Comment: Not a big user of PHP but `explode` would split on spaces, right ? so `pieces[0] = "(400,"` and `pieces[1] = 530);`. EDIT : Ow, you correcte it ^^

Comment: No, you can easily specify a delimiter.. like there, where I use ";". See more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php (oh, you was faster than me.. :) )

Comment: @Richard There are 9,000 lines in the file, each with 100 values=900,000 values per file (and i have 6 text files that the HTML page might have to reference), so a lot. Is this method still applicable with such large numbers?

Comment: @Richard like I have said in the edit, you have change your code, you initially use `" "` not `";"`...

Comment: I do not know what you want to do with that data. Therefore, it is difficult to recommend something. Generally, 9,000 lines of text per 100 values is not a memory issue.